# How do I get ranked for terms which do not have related published content?

Tags: seo, google-search

My site is database driven site for educational courses. I around 200 courses list with me.
The users I am targeting search for terms like MBA in finance, Computer engineering Graduates. Now I can create multitude of these posts with various permutations and combinations but they do not provide much value to readers.
Can I create sitemap links for these posts and submit to search engines and when user access the link, show the data dynamically by parsing the url ?

Is there a smarter way to achieve the ranking for these terms ?

The example I look at is Amazon or overstock which can rank for numerous terms which is just a category or subcategory. They do not have content for each of those terms.

Comment: @dan Sorry Dan. I guess I jumped on my soap box too quickly!

Comment: @closetnoc NP. I was just adding an explanation why this was put on hold, and the rest you covered well.

Comment: @vsingh In addition to being somewhat unclear (i.e., the title doesn't match the questions being asked), the final question is too broad and will result in opinion-based answers.

Comment: @dan I will update the question

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. There is a better way. Do it the traditional way. Really. I am not saying that you cannot have dynamic pages, just do not try and game the system. Create solid and valuable content for the topics and sub-topics you have. You can make it database driven so that courses can be added and deleted if you want. That would be a good idea.

You do not want thin content and you do not content made for machines. Trust me when I say, SEO, while keywords are important, is becoming less and less keyword centric and much more semantic. It all began in 2008 with Google Scholar and semantic search has elevated to a level that you would not believe. Even the slightest keyword loading/gaming will fail. It is not so much that Google is looking for gaming anymore, but that gaming fails the semantic ranking mechanisms.

BTW- if you have a small site, your sitemap will be ignored. Google and Bing prefer to spider sites, but will differ to the sitemap for larger sites. A site with a few hundred pages is a small site. If you want to have a dynamic site, then forego the sitemap if your site is small. Make sure that all of the pages can be found through links. As well, definitely do not use the sitemap for anything other than one to one mapping of pages. DO NOT use it to game systems. This is one area you do not want to play around with.

Do not try and game SEO. You will always lose. Do honest work. Really. If it makes it easier, use a CMS or blogging software. Wordpress, for example, yields excellent SEO.

Comment: The intention was not to game the system but how to get ranked without losing value from reader's perspective, bit I got your point. Great piece of advice.